# RoR 3 Creating an Invoice app - How do I create the form for a HABTM invoice/products association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm attempting to make an invoice application.  Here are my models which are related to my question:

UPDATE: Model information has changed due to recent suggestions

```
Invoice  
> id  
> created_at  
> sales_person_id

LineItem
> id  
> invoice_id  
> item_id  
> qty_commit (inventory only)  
> qty_sold  
> price (because prices change)  
> ...etc

Item
> barcode  
> name  
> price
> ...etc
```

Invoice `has_many items, :through => :line_items`. Ditto for Item.  What I want to do is that when I create a new invoice, I'd like the form to be populated with all available Items.  The only time I don't want all items to be populated is when I'm viewing the invoice (so only items which exist in the LineItems table should be retrieved).  Currently - and obviously - a new Invoice has no items.  How do I get them listed when there is nothing currently in the collection, and how do I populate the form?  Also I'd like all products to be available when creation fails (along with what the user selected through the form).

UPDATE: I can create items through the controller via the following:

> @invoice = Invoice.new
>   # Populate the invoice with all products so that they can be selected
>   Item.where("stock > ?", 0).each do |i|
>   @invoice.items.new(i.attributes)
>   end

This is of course my crude attempt at doing what I want.  Visually it works out great, but as predicted my form id's and such are not playing well when I actually attempt to save the model.

> LineItem(#37338684) expected, got Array(#2250012)

An example of the form:

> # f is form_for
>   <% @invoice.items.group_by{|p| p.category}.each do |category, products| %>
>   
>     <%= category.name %>
>   
>   <%= f.fields_for :line_items do |line_item| %>
>   <% for p in products %>
>     
>         <%= line_item.hidden_field :tax_included, :value => p.tax_included %>
>         <%= p.name %>
>         $<%= p.price %>
>     
>   <% end %>
>   <% end %>
>   <% end %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you explicitly want to have a join model with additional attributes in it, you should use `has_many :through` instead of `has_and_belongs_to_many`. See the [RoR Guide to the differences](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many) of the two.

Second, there is no single solution for what you want to reach. I see there two typical usages, depending on the mass of possible instances, one is better than the other:

1. Use radio buttons to select (and deselect) where a relation should be created or deleted. See the [railscast #165](http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple?view=asciicast) how to do part of that.
2. You could use select menus with a button to add a relation. See [railscast #88](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus). The added relation could be shown in a list, with a delete button nearby.
3. Use token fields (see [railscast #258](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields)) to autocomplete multiple entries in one single text entry field.

In all the situations, you normally have to check at the end, if

- a relation should be deleted
- kept
- or created

I hope some of the ideas may show you the right solution for your problem.

---

Comment: I currently have the controller set up so that it retrieves all of the products from the items table.  The view utilizes that, but the id's of the form inputs are unique and so it wouldn't be considered part of the Invoice model once the submit button is hit.  How do I create the id's of each form element so that I don't have to do any extra work through the controller when I intend to save the model?