# Rails model relationship and forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, select2-rails

When I want to create a new purchase as shown below, I would like to replace the name and price input.

```
<%= simple_form_for([@order, @purchase])  do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :quantity %>
    <%= f.input :price %>

    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

For the name input, I would like to have a collection that saves the id of a selected product 
(from the product table).

As for the price input, I would like to display the price of the selected product above, have the price saved to the purchases table.

```
### #models
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :purchases, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :products
end

class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :order
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :orders
end
```

Relationships and coding them into forms confuses me at times.

I would assume that the models should be set up as follows:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :purchases, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :products, :through => :purchases
end

class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :order
 belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :purchases
 has_many :orders, :through => :purchases
end
```

Then I would create the product_id column in purchases. If this is correct, how would I then create the collection code and print the price of the selected item (in the collection) in the form?

Writing the code for the relationship is where I get stuck.

I would like to also use the `rails-select2` gem.

Comment: I don't have the exact answer, but since I can't comment yet, I have to post here.
You may find the following link to be useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844568/ror-3-creating-an-invoice-app-how-do-i-create-the-form-for-a-habtm-invoice-pro